# Python-polars: from coefficients, values and (nested) lists to weighted values

Tags: python, python-polars

Let's say I've got a Polars DataFrame similar to this one:

```py
import polars as pl
from decimal import Decimal

pl.Config.activate_decimals()

pl.from_dicts(
    [
        {"id": 1, "value": Decimal("100.0"), "items": ["A"]},
        {"id": 2, "value": Decimal("150.000"), "items": ["A", "B"]},
        {"id": 3, "value": Decimal("70.0000"), "items": ["A", "B", "C"]},
    ]
)
```

| id *→ pl.Int64* | value *→ pl.Decimal* | items *→ pl.List(str)* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | `["A"]` |
| 2 | 150 | `["A", "B"]` |
| 3 | 70 | `["A", "B", "C"]` |

And the following Python dictionary:

```py
coef = {"A": Decimal("0.2"), "B": Decimal("0.35"), "C": Decimal("0.45") }
```

From here, how to **get the following DataFrame** in an efficient manner **using Polars**?

| id *→ pl.Int64* | value *→ pl.Decimal* | item *→ str* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | "A" |
| 2 | 54.5454545454545454 | "A" |
| 2 | 95.4545454545454545 | "B" |
| 3 | 14.00000 | "A" |
| 3 | 24.500000 | "B" |
| 3 | 31.500000 | "C" |

In this example, `54.5454...` for instance corresponds to `0.2 / (0.2 + 0.35) * 150`.

I've tried various things using `.explode` ([doc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.explode.html)), `.map_dict` ([doc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_dict.html)), `.when` / `.then` / `.otherwise` / `.cast` with `.arr.lengths` ([doc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.arr.lengths.html)), but I'm still struggling to get the expected output in a clean way.

Note that the length of the `coef` dictionary isn't always the same. It basically looks like `{key1: coef1, key2: coef2, ... }` with `n` keys and `n` values (whose sum is equal to `Decimal(1)`). Also, I'm working with `Decimal` (not `float64` values), even if this is an "*experimental work-in-progress feature*" (see [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4104#issuecomment-1484830343)). I'm using `polars '0.17.2'`.

Comment: Could you articulate the formula for all the values instead of just the 54.545454 example. I realize it seems obvious to you because you're in it everyday but random people on the internet are seeing it for the first time.

Comment: For instance, the id3 items seem to just be the 70 * whatever is in the coef but the id2 is the other formula and id1 seems to ignore the coef.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor that was probably not explicit, indeed: in the initial DataFrame, row with `id = 2` contains 2 items (`"A"` and `"B"`), thus in the expected output the row corresponding to `"A"` will be the initial value (`150`) multiplied by the weight of A (`0.2`) divided by the total weight (weight of A `0.2` + weight of B `0.35`). At the end of the day, we get `0.2 / (0.2 + 0.35) * 150`. `C` is irrelevant here, its weight is equal to `0` in the initial value and should not be taken into account. Am I clear?

Answer (score 1):

One way to write it could be:

```
df.explode("items").with_columns(
   coef = pl.col("items").map_dict(coef)
).with_columns(
   pl.col("coef") / pl.col("coef").sum().over("id") * pl.col("value")
)
```

```
shape: (6, 4)
┌─────┬──────────┬───────┬───────────────┐
│ id  ┆ value    ┆ items ┆ coef          │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---           │
│ i64 ┆ f64      ┆ str   ┆ f64           │
╞═════╪══════════╪═══════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1e6      ┆ A     ┆ 1e6           │
│ 2   ┆ 1.5e6    ┆ A     ┆ 545454.545455 │
│ 2   ┆ 1.5e6    ┆ B     ┆ 954545.454545 │
│ 3   ┆ 700000.0 ┆ A     ┆ 140000.0      │
│ 3   ┆ 700000.0 ┆ B     ┆ 245000.0      │
│ 3   ┆ 700000.0 ┆ C     ┆ 315000.0      │
└─────┴──────────┴───────┴───────────────┘
```

However, with Decimals, it raises an exception:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'not implemented for Decimal(None, Some(2))', 
./git/polars/polars/polars-lazy/src/physical_plan/expressions/window.rs:685:9
```

```
PanicException: not implemented for Decimal(None, Some(2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I stumbled over a very similar Exception before to ask for help here, indeed...

Comment: @scūriolus Okay. It probably needs to be filed as a bug on the issues tracker.

Comment: done [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8201), thank you again for your time